# To-do application in React

Tags: beginner, react.js, jsx, to-do-list

I am new to react and I tried to implement a TODO application using react state and props. I need somebody to just review the code and suggest improvements in the code. Currently I have not added any CSS to it, I am focusing more on react practices. code sandbox link- https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-archimedes-se4vm

App.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import InputForm from './InputForm';
import ShowTODO from './ShowTODO'
import Choices from './Choices';
import {useState} from 'react'

function App(props) {
  const [todoList, setTODOList] = useState([]);
  const [filterName, setFilterName] = useState("active");

  const addTODO = (event, todoInput) => {
    // if you do not do this then if form submit is clicked
    // then page will refresh and everything will go
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentTODO = {"state": "active", "data": todoInput};
    var previousTODOList = [...todoList];
    previousTODOList.push(currentTODO);
    setTODOList(previousTODOList);
  }

  const updateFilterName = (event) => {
    let newFilterName = event.target.value;
    setFilterName(newFilterName);
    console.log(todoList);
  }

  const updateTODOStatus = (index, newState) => {
    let previousTODOList = [...todoList];
    previousTODOList[index]["state"] = newState;
    setTODOList(previousTODOList);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InputForm onSubmit={addTODO}/>
      <Choices filterName={filterName} onChange={(e) => updateFilterName(e)}/>
      <p>
        {filterName}
      </p>
      <ShowTODO filterName={filterName} todoList={todoList} updateStatus={updateTODOStatus}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Choices.jsx

```
function Choices(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={props.filterName} onChange={(event)=>props.onChange(event)}>
        <option value="active"> Show active to do </option>
        <option value="completed"> Show completed to do </option>
        <option value="all"> Show all to do </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Choices;
```

InputForm.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react'

function InputForm(props) {
  const [todoInput, setTODOInput] = useState("");
  const addTODO = (event)=>{
    props.onSubmit(event, todoInput);
  }
  const updateInputValue = (event) => {
    setTODOInput(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="InputForm">
      <form onSubmit={addTODO}>
        <input
        type="text"
        name="todo-input"
        id="todo-input"
        value={todoInput}
        onChange={(event)=>updateInputValue(event)}
        />
        <button> Add To Do </button>
      </form>
    </div>
);
}

export default InputForm;
```

ShowTODO.jsx

```
function ShowTODO(props) {
  return (
      <div>
        {
          props.todoList.map((todo, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                {todo.state === "active" && props.filterName === "active" && <span> {todo.data} Mark as complete <input type="checkbox" onClick={()=>props.updateStatus(index, "completed")}/> </span> }
                {todo.state === "completed" && props.filterName === "completed" && <span> {todo.data} Mark as active <input type="checkbox" onClick={()=>props.updateStatus(index, "active")}/> </span>}
                {props.filterName === "all" && <span> {todo.data} </span>}
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
  );
}

export default ShowTODO;
```